# How to get back to the previous spider in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to do one thing. I have a spider written using Scrapy. It has two parse function like the following

```
def parse(self, response):

   ...
   for var in dict
      ...

      scrapy.Request(link + var, callback=self.parse_info)


 def parse_info(self, response)

    ...
    do something
```

What I would like to do is getting data in `parse_info` and after finished come back to the parse method to continue the iteration. Does exist a way to do this in scrapy?

Comment: Don't try to cram too many things in a single parse function. A function should do just 1 thing.

def parse():

def parse_info():

def parse_more_info(): etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will use 'Yield' in your parse call and 'return' in your parse_info call

```
def parse(self, response):

...
for var in dict
  ...

  yield Request(item['page_url'], callback=self.parse_info)


def parse_info(self, response)

  ...
  do something
  return something
```

Comment: Are you sure that doing that I come back continuing to iterate?

Comment: Unforuntately it is not what I need. When parse_info finish to execute, it continue to iterate in the parse method but I can't call anymore any return inside the parse. Instead I would call return to return a dictionary inside parse

Comment: @eng_mazzy: yes I am very much sure because this is how all my scrapers work, I don't know if you need it or not but this is exactly how it works and this is the answer to your question. You might be more precious with your questions and comments. Things like call a 'return' doesn't not exist at least I didn't hear about such. You might return a value or not when you call a function. Marking my answer as negative while submitting such kind of comments is more then ridiculous.